# Declaration is only valid at file scope error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can anybody explain me why the extension work this way.

I've written an extension for my main ViewController which includes a function:

```
extension WeatherMainScreen {
    func load(lat: Double, long: Double){
        service.getWeatherInfo(lat: lat, long: long) { [weak self] temp in
            self?.tempNumber.text = "\(temp.currently.temperature)"
            self?.results = temp.daily.data
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem is that if I put this extension under the ViewController class I get an error "Declaration is only valid at file scope". But if I put above it works fine.

Weird part(for me) is that in this particular project my ViewController class is kind of big, but if i try this exactly extension in a different project which has much smaller ViewController class and put extension under it everything works ok showing no errors.

The question is - why putting the extension above the VC Class works, but if I put under the VC Class it shows this "Declaration is only valid at file scope" error?

More explanation

This way it doesn’t work showing Declaration error:

```
class WeatherMainScreen: UIViewController {
}
extension WeatherMainScreen {
// your code
}
```

This way it works:

```
extension WeatherMainScreen {
// your code
}
class WeatherMainScreen: UIViewController {
}
```

I do not put extension inside the class

Comment: What is the exact question? Also you mention you get an error, can you add the error?

Comment: kindly add the error which you got !

Comment: Sorry, fixed the text.

Comment: Are you adding the extension in your class file? It needs be at root level?

Comment: yeap, right into my class file

Comment: can you add image of your error?

Answer (score 2):

**The question is - why putting the extension above the VC Class works, but if I put under the VC Class it shows this "Declaration is only valid at file scope" error?**

Answer: Extensions should be at the root level, not inside any class.

This is wrong. As the extension is nested inside the `WeatherMainScreen`

```
class WeatherMainScreen: UIViewController { 
    extension WeatherMainScreen { // wrong as its declared inside the WeatherMainScreen
    // your code
    }
}
```

This is correct, as the extension is declared at the root level

```
class WeatherMainScreen: UIViewController {
}
extension WeatherMainScreen { // correct way.
// your code
}
```

Comment: @navsegda then please explain again.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. It works fine for me.  better clean your project and run again.

Answer (score 0):

ViewController size does not matter. Putting view controller anywhere will work. You can read more about access modifiers of Swift from [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html).

Also make sure you `WeatherMainScreen` is `public` or `open` class.